# QSerialPort ошибки настройки.

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator

Добрый день! 
Написал небольшую программку по работе с QSerialPort, программа ищет COM port и подключается к ним. Возникла проблема, не меняются значение в FlowControl, Parity. Код напишу отрывками. Если что нужно будет, добавлю. 
Структура настройки порта.

```
struct Settings {
    QString name;
    qint32 baudRate;
    QSerialPort::DataBits dataBits;
    QSerialPort::Parity parity;
    QSerialPort::StopBits stopBits;
    QSerialPort::FlowControl flowControl;
};
```

Функция принимающая настройки

```
void Port :: Write_Settings_Port(QString name, int baudrate,int DataBits,
                         int Parity,int StopBits, int FlowControl){
    SettingsPort.name = name;
    SettingsPort.baudRate = (QSerialPort::BaudRate) baudrate;
    SettingsPort.dataBits = (QSerialPort::DataBits) DataBits;
    SettingsPort.parity = (QSerialPort::Parity) Parity;
    SettingsPort.stopBits = (QSerialPort::StopBits) StopBits;
    SettingsPort.flowControl = (QSerialPort::FlowControl) FlowControl;
}
```

Пользователь выбирает данные настройки из QComboBox.

```
 ui->BaudRateBox->addItem(QLatin1String("9600"), QSerialPort::Baud9600);
    ui->BaudRateBox->addItem(QLatin1String("19200"), QSerialPort::Baud19200);
    ui->BaudRateBox->addItem(QLatin1String("38400"), QSerialPort::Baud38400);
    ui->BaudRateBox->addItem(QLatin1String("115200"), QSerialPort::Baud115200);
    ui->BaudRateBox->addItem(QLatin1String("Custom"));
   // fill data bits
    ui->DataBitsBox->addItem(QLatin1String("5"), QSerialPort::Data5);
    ui->DataBitsBox->addItem(QLatin1String("6"), QSerialPort::Data6);
    ui->DataBitsBox->addItem(QLatin1String("7"), QSerialPort::Data7);
    ui->DataBitsBox->addItem(QLatin1String("8"), QSerialPort::Data8);
    ui->DataBitsBox->setCurrentIndex(3);

    ui->ParityBox->addItem(QLatin1String("None"), QSerialPort::NoParity);
    ui->ParityBox->addItem(QLatin1String("Even"), QSerialPort::EvenParity);
    ui->ParityBox->addItem(QLatin1String("Odd"), QSerialPort::OddParity);
    ui->ParityBox->addItem(QLatin1String("Mark"), QSerialPort::MarkParity);
    ui->ParityBox->addItem(QLatin1String("Space"), QSerialPort::SpaceParity);

        ui->StopBitsBox->addItem(QLatin1String("1"), QSerialPort::OneStop);
        ui->StopBitsBox->addItem(QLatin1String("2"), QSerialPort::TwoStop);

  ui->FlowControlBox->addItem(QLatin1String("None"), QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    ui->FlowControlBox->addItem(QLatin1String("RTS/CTS"), QSerialPort::HardwareControl);
    ui->FlowControlBox->addItem(QLatin1String("XON/XOFF"), QSerialPort::SoftwareControl)
```

Так вот, меняются только Baudrate, DataBit, StopBit - остальные значения не меняются. 
Сигнал который изменяет значения.

```
void SavePortSetting(QString name, int baudrate, int DataBits, int Parity, int StopBits, int FlowControl);
```

В документации по QT сказано, что Flow Contorl и Parity - это enum. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Что за сигнал? Куда подключен? Как вызывается? В чем именно вопрос: проблема с сигналом или `В документации по QT сказано, что Flow Contorl и Parity - это enum. `?

Comment: Сигнал с параметрами передается по нажатию кнопки. Который передает данные в фукцию. Данные берет из QComboBox, в которых задает значения пользователь.

Comment: Вот это и нужно показать в коде в вопросе. А так гадать что у вас происходит в коде смысла мало